# Problem on displaying collapse/expand icon using *ngFor in mat-expansion-panel on angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor, formarray, mat-expansion-panel

I have a customized icon for collapse and expand. As I have a nested array, It will trigger all header. It should be click first header that only expand in 1 st header. It should not trigger all header. How to separate control it ? [Here is stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eyn1pp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a boolan for evry posts open/close